# Ajax call will not work without preventDefault

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-ajax

In an MVC page, I have the following jQuery/javascript:

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    var inp = $("input"); inp.attr('value', inp.val());
    var html = replaceAll(replaceAll($('html')[0].outerHTML, "<", "&lt;"), ">", "&lt;");
    // event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Ajax/SetSession",
        asynch: false,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        type: "get",
        data: { name: 'html', data: html.substring(0, 1024) },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Ouch! " + xhr.responseText);
            // $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Awesome: " + data);
            // $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            alert('Phew!');
            $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

It is meant to intercept the normal submit process, capture the html of the page before it's submitted, and then continue on its way as if nothing happened.

But the problem is, with both commented out, the form re-submits, as expected, put the controller never executes the /Ajax/SetSession url. Whereas, if I uncomment them, the /Ajax/SetSession does execute but the unbind does not appear to work as the form does not seem to get resubmitted.

Not sure what's going on here. What am I missing?

Any and all clues appreciated.

Comment: It is `async` not `asynch`. your current code here will run the ajax in async mode, which means it won't wait for response and continue the form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault();` should stay uncommented since this prevents form to submit instantly. Apparently you want to control the moment at which form is submitted.

`$(this).unbind` does not work because inside success and error handles context is no longer form - it is an jQuery ajax context object. You can do two things here to have the behavior you want:

1. Set context explicitly to be the form object. This can be done via `context` property:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       ...
       context: this, //form here!
       ...
       success: function (data) {
           alert("Awesome: " + data);
           $(this).unbind('submit').submit(); //now this refers to form
       },
   ```
2. Refer to form using a different variable:

   ```
   $("form").submit(function (event) {
       var form = this;
       ...
       $.ajax({
           ...
           success: function (data) {
               alert("Awesome: " + data);
               $(form).unbind('submit').submit(); //using form variable instead of this
           },
   ```